# Import LDAP member of records into sql database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays, ldap

We are looking to export our users from LDAP to a table in SQL.

I can import the names and other information from LDAP however I am unable to import the memberof information.

I know this is an array but unsure on how to obtain this in an sql query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about grabing data from **Active Directory** using the SQL Server ADO provider? Then you're out of luck - that provider is rather "limited" (some would say "crippled") and one of the things it **doesn't support** are attributes that have multiple values - like `memberOf` .

Comment: do you need MemberOf attribute to get group information user belongs to?

Comment: I need a list of all users including their associated group memberships. EG CN=user,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local would display multiple entries from memberof

Comment: I believe you need to do this in two steps. First you need to get User data and then for every user you need to query Group that user belong to OU=Groups,OU=Secured Objects,DC=domain,DC=local.

Comment: @Leigh what tools are you working with? (i.e. extracting, loading, database, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have user information you can store that information to temporary table. For every user then you can probably query group objects to get group information.
I have below code for single SamAccountName. You will need to wrapped this code in loop to get group membership for all users.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp 
    (   GroupName varchar(100),
        Usercode varchar(100)   );
DECLARE @ldap varchar(40); -- LDAP server name
DECLARE @LdapUsername NVARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @Query nVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @Path nVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @Query1 nVARCHAR(max);



            SELECT @LdapUsername = 'hshah' -- SAMAccountName


            SET @Query = '
                SELECT @Path = distinguishedName
                FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, ''
                    SELECT distinguishedName 
                    FROM ''''' + @ldap + '/ou=users,ou=Test,DC=domain,DC=local''''
                    WHERE 
                        objectClass = ''''user'''' AND
                        sAMAccountName = ''''' + @LdapUsername + '''''
                '')
            '
            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query, N'@Path NVARCHAR(1024) OUTPUT', @Path = @Path OUTPUT 

            SELECT @Path = REPLACE(@Path,'''','')


            SET @Query = '
                SELECT name AS LdapGroup, ''' + @LdapUsername +''' as Usercode
                FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,''
                    SELECT name 
                    FROM ''''' + @ldap + '/OU=Groups,OU=Secured Objects,DC=domain,DC=local''''
                    WHERE 
                        objectClass=''''group'''' AND'
            SET @Query1 = '
                        member=''''' + @Path + '''''
                '')
                ORDER BY name
                '


            INSERT INTO #tmp
            EXEC (@Query + @Query1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to use frameworks, you could use Spring LDAP with JAVA and get all records as objects (list of objects) and then you could use JDBC to connect to your database and insert the records as per your table schema.

Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/